# Autocomplete with Bootstrap double dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When using Bootstrap's autocomplete feature, I get two drop downs lists (seemingly the browser-default one) only when I include strings that include spaces as options.

A) I've tried autocomplete="off" to no avail
B) This is fine:

```
 data-source='["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"]' />
```

C) This gives the double drop downs:

```
 data-source='["Two words", "Anything else"]' />
```

D) Even this gives double drop downs:

```
data-source='["Two&nbsp;words", "Anything&nbsp;else"]'
```

E) The example in the Bootstrap docs handles spaces fine...

F) Yes, my DOCTYPE is HTML5

Any idea why this is and how I might fix it?

Thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the stupid question--I had an additional reference to bootstrap-typeahead.js that was doubling it up.